# Error integrating Samba with already configured Openldap

Tags: windows, active-directory, centos7, ldap, samba

After setting up my Openldap on Centos 7, I got a problem while integrating Samba
(I followed many tutorials, ex. https://admin.shamot.cz/?p=470).

After running the command:

```
net getlocalsid
```

I got an error:

> ailed to bind to server ldap://172.16.0.180 with dn="cn=ldapadm"
> Error: Invalid credentials
> (unknown) pdb_init_ldapsam: WARNING: Could not get domain info, nor add one to the domain. We cannot work reliably without it.
> pdb backend ldapsam:ldap://172.16.0.180 did not correctly init (error
> was NT_STATUS_CANT_ACCESS_DOMAIN_INFO) WARNING: Could not open passdb